# Access pod inside a custom cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

This is a custom cocoapod which connect with Alamofire. How can i access Alamofire pod imported in my code.

```
let SDKConnect = Networking()
class Networking {

var AFManager = Alamofire.SessionManager()
init() {
    AFManager = {
        let trustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [ "example.com": .disableEvaluation ]
        let AFConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        AFConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
        AFConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
        AFConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager( configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: trustPolicies) )
        return manager
    }()
}
```

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Alamofire'

[image: Pod structure]

[image: Target membership]

Comment: Did you import the framework using `import Alamofire` in the file `Networking.swift`?

Comment: No, when i import alamofire `No such module 'Alamofire'` response is given. I have only ticked the taget membership as in above pic @phil

Comment: The file Networking.swift should not be ticked for Alamofire nor SwiftyJSON, but you need to check WebConnect, as it is part of that framework

Comment: No i cannot access it even added webconnect. Do you have any correct implementation sample for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attached a given example and here is the guide on how to create it:

**Project:**

- `pod lib create WebConnnect` to create the initial project (go with the default answers).
- Run `pod deintegrate` in the `Examples` folder, to remove the initial dependencies from the Xcode workspace
- Add the following code to the `WebConnect.podspec`:

`Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  ...

  s.dependency 'Alamofire'
  s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON'
end`

- Remove the version numbers for `Nimble`, `Quick`, `FBSnapshotTestCase` and `Nimble-Snapshots` in the Podfile, as these are outdated by default anyway.
- Now run `pod install` and `pod update`, to ensure the newest dependencies are installed.

**Code:**

Rename the file `ReplaceMe.swift` to `Networking.swift` in the folder `Development Pods/WebConnect` and make sure its Target Membership is the target `WebConnect`.

Now add the following code to the file (it is basically yours, but I added the import of Alamofire):

```
import Alamofire

let SDKConnect = Networking()
class Networking {

    var AFManager = Alamofire.SessionManager()
    init() {
        AFManager = {
            let trustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [ "example.com": .disableEvaluation ]
            let AFConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            AFConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
            AFConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15
            AFConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15
            let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager( configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: trustPolicies) )
            return manager
        }()
    }
}
```

Download: [Hosted by WeTransfer](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/db934f1705feaf49d679afeb2f77a3d020181126094112/e00644)

Comment: Thank you very much brother. its working. Thanks for ur effort.

Comment: how did you add that info.plist file to the project ?

Comment: Which info.plist do you mean?

Comment: Pods > Development pods > support files > info.plist .  my project doesnt have that file. i need it for adding  ATS trust policy

Comment: sorry i got it.

Comment: The file has been added by the Cocoapods template, but as a general rule you can add ANY file you want to the Xcode workspace, just by dragging it to a folder from Finder, *WITHOUT* checking "Copy Items if needed" und *ONLY* check a target box if the file needs to be included. Info.plist has no target as it should not!

Answer (score 1):

In the `.podspec` file of your custom pod add `Alamofire` as a dependency, something like this:

```
spec.dependency 'Alamofire'
```

and then do `pod repo push`, then `pod update YourCustomPod` and then you'll be able to use `Alamofire`

Comment: ........
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots

 ` # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  # s.frameworks = 'UIKit'
  s.dependency 'Alamofire'
  s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON'`

Comment: How to share that file ?